# Plug A Custom Membership And Role Provider Into MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a custom user database that's quite locked down.  I can only access it through stored procedures. I need to get this database to work with MVC so here's what I have so far.

A Repository that accesses a class that can manipulate the database.
A Class that inherits ExtendedMembershipProvider and a class that inherits RoleProvider.

I now need to plug these Providers into MVC but this is where I'm struggling.

If I create a new MVC4 project based on the Internet Application Template then everything seems to be geared around SimpleMembership.  I can't even see where in the web.config the providers are declared. I see the AccountController has a lot of references to the ModelState and WebSecurity but I'm not sure where or how I tell these to use my providers.  As I'm not using EF I also have my own User and Role Models.

If I create a new MVC project based on the "Basic" template then I can see the providers in the web.config but there is no Account Controller so I'm not sure how to properly create this.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. My aim is to be able to use all the usual [AllowAnonymous] [Authorize] etc.. tags in the controllers + IsAuthenticated, User.IsInRole etc.... in my Razor view files.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
[EFMVC.Web.Core](https://github.com/shijuvar/EFMVC.Azure/tree/master/EFMVC.Web.Core)

and you can use this approach for your role management too

Comment: This seems like overkill as I'm not trying to use EF or EF CodeFirst.

Comment: it does not have anything to do with EF at all. just look at authentication parts.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue using Razor.

see if this Helps : 
http://ratiyaranmal.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/custom-membership-provider-mvc.html